# AngularJS: Why is it (apparently) not necessary to declare a variable for ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Chances are other people are confused with this phoenomenon, so I post this question here.

***HTML***

```
<select 
    ng-model="cont.selectedItem" 
    ng-options="item.name for item in cont.lists.items" >
</select>

//"cont" indicates the controller. $scope is not used here

<span ng-click="addNewItem()">add</span>
```

***JS***

```
var instance = this;
instance.list = { ...item instances... };
instance.selectedItem;//Is it really necessary?

instance.addNewItem = function() {
  var  item = instance.selectedItem;
  ...
}
```

I used to believe that `selectedItem`, which is used in the `ng-model`, had to be declared as `instance.selectedItem` in JS, so that I could see which `item` was chosen in the `ng-options`.

However, I noticed that the `var item` in the `addNewItem` function gets the selected item, **even when `instance.selectedItem` is commented out**.

I went to the Angular's documentation, but I can't find out why.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: `selectedItem` is a property, not a variable. `instance.selectedItem` is a property access that does nothing (and returns `undefined` if it doesn't exist), not a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you are defining a primitive type variable inside `this` context of controller, where by default that value of `selectedItem` is undefined as `this` has already been defined :) . In this when angular `$parser` sets an value. That operation is pretty straight forward. Behind the scene `$parse` do this thing for you.

Let me show you another example where you can see the actual magic made by `$parse` API. Suppose you wanted to set value for `model.something` where `model` object haven't been defined yet. Lets pass that value to `$parse` API and assign some value to it(see below code would help you to understand). The same thing will happen when you have assigned `model.something` value to `ng-model` directive. Whenever you change the value of `ng-model` value it `assign`s a value to underlying variable of its context.

Below is example that illustrate how `$parse` does work.

```
mainMod.controller('MainCtrl', ['$parse','$interpolate','$compile',
    function ($parse,$interpolate,$compile) {
         var vm = this; 

         //$parse
         vm.parse = $parse('model.something');
         //assigning value to `model.something` from `vm`
         //so the value is going to put inside `vm`
         //while assigning a value it check that value exists or not
         //if it isn't exist then it creates an value inside mentioned context
         //here context is `vm`(this)
         vm.parse.assign(vm, 'Pankaj'); 
         console.log(vm.model); //vm.model will have { something: 'Prakash' }
    }
]);
```